# The maximum quantity allowed message on 404 page With magento SCP module

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have installed OrganicInternet Simple Configurable Product (SCP) module on magento 1.9.2.

I have added "Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" settings for a product to 1. Whenever I add a qty greater than 1, it redirects to siteurl/catalog/product/view/.

It shows the error message "The maximum quantity allowed for purchase is 1.", but on a 404 page. The issue is only for configurable products. I am using magento 1.9.2.

The code changes mentioned in the below thread is present on the module.

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/issues/40.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

[screen-shot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEp6u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the SCP module to the latest version solves the issue.

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

Thanks...